# Encoding error in getting values from web page with agilitypack

Tags: c#, encoding, html-agility-pack

as a newbie in programming, i would appreciate any help you can provide. I am trying to make a telephone lookup in c# . The content of the web page is in Greek and i cannot get other text than @#@#$@###@########. Only Latin characters are shown. Tried a lot of encoding methods but nothing so far. Thank you in advance for all your advices.

code=

string url = "http://www.11888.gr/list-names?_wpType=number&_wpPhone=2107255555";

```
                System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);

               byte[] byteArray = wc.DownloadData(new Uri(url));
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                   htmlDoc.Load(stream);

               var SpanNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='details']");    

                if (SpanNodes != null)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode SN in SpanNodes)
                    {
                        string text = SN.InnerText.Trim();

                        richTextBox1.Text = text;


                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UTF8 encoding.

```
       System.Text.Encoding utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        // unicode string:
        string unicodeStr = "étext";
        // Convert string to utf-8 bytes to transport 
        byte[] byteBuffUtf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unicodeStr);
        // Convert back utf-8 to display ready string.
        string myUnicode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBuffUtf8);
        MessageBox.Show(myUnicode);
```

Here is MSDN sample

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx